# Piece of Chatbot code not executing because of indentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my chatbot, I made a list called 'greetings'. It contains standard greetings, 'Hi', 'Hello, 'What's up', etc. I want to make it so that if it outputs 'What's up?' and the user responds 'not much' or whatever, it responds with 'Cool' and other things among that. I assume python lists (marked with []) start from 0, in which case it's `greetings[3]`, like so:

```py
#setting up
greetings = ['Hi', 'Hello!', 'Greetings', 'What\'s up?', 'Good day', 'What\'s good?']
howru = ['Surprisingly well', 'Very good' , 'Good', 'I\'m doing well, you?' 'Not too good', 'Could be better', 'I\'m terrible today, thanks for asking']
dontknow = ['I don\'t understand', 'Say again?', 'I don\'t know about that one', 'I\'m sorry, I don\'t understand.']

def Bot():
    print('Welcome to Almost Human, your (Almost) human  friend.\nTry starting with a greeting!')
    while(True):
        a = input('You: ')
        if a.lower() in('hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'what\'s up', 'greetings', 'wass good'):
            botgreetings = random.choice(greetings)
            print('AlmostHuman: ' + botgreetings)
            if botgreetings == greetings[3]:
                if a.lower() == 'not much':
                    print('AlmostHuman: Cool.')
                elif a.lower() == 'the ceiling' or a.lower() == 'the sky':
                    print('AlmostHuman: You think you\'re funny, do you?')
        else:
            print('AlmostHuman: ' + random.choice(dontknow))
Bot()
```

However, when It gets to "What's up" and I put 'not much', it responds with "I don't understand" (because it's the `else` to the `python
if a.lower() == blah`. I tried putting the code 4 spaces backwards, and that fixed the problem, actually. But since it was now the spot where the `else` was, it responds with:

```
AlmostHuman: Cool
AlmostHuman: I don't understand
```

when I enter 'not much'.

I think it's an indentation problem, but I have no idea, I've been trying to fix this for months.

This is my first question, so excuse if I wasn't specific enough! :)

EDIT: Greetings is defined here:

```py
#setting up
greetings = ['Hi', 'Hello!', 'Greetings', 'What\'s up?', 'Good day', 'What\'s good?']
howru = ['Surprisingly well', 'Very good' , 'Good', 'I\'m doing well, you?' 'Not too good', 'Could be better', 'I\'m terrible today, thanks for asking']
dontknow = ['I don\'t understand', 'Say again?', 'I don\'t know about that one', 'I\'m sorry, I don\'t understand.']

#bot begins here
def Bot():
```

Along with other lists.

The `else:` is at the very end of the code, here:

```py
        else:
            print('AlmostHuman: ' + random.choice(dontknow))
Bot()
```

Comment: Where is `greetings` defined? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, this - including where "I don't understand" is printed.

Comment: I added the information to my post.

Comment: @TrebledJ Doesn't matter, the `"what's up"` in the tuple is a user input check, the `"what's up?"` is a response from the bot

Comment: @EzPzPython The first and most noticeable problem, is that you check to make sure `a.lower()` is one of `('hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'what\'s up', 'greetings', 'wass good')`, but then you also expect it to be one of `'not much', 'the ceiling', 'the sky'`. You're going to need the user to input another message first

Comment: Also you should change the tuple `('hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'what\'s up', 'greetings', 'wass good')` to a `set`: `{'hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'what\'s up', 'greetings', 'wass good'}`. This isn't the issue but it will make the program faster.

Answer (score 0):

When you check a.lower() the second time, it still has the value from the original input(), and because you check it the second time inside the top level if it will never == 'not much'

Comment: Tried adding another input inside the if statement, called b. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! I made another input in that if statement called ```b``` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First:
Using `Bot()` is missleading to a classname if you follow the PEP8 style guide.

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Second your input will stop by:

```
if a.lower() in('hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'what\'s up', 'greetings', 'wass good'):
```

becouse `not much` is not in this list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're forgetting to ask for more input after `if botgreetings == greetings[3]:`, so if you say `'not much'` here you actually saying that to the input at the start of the loop (because you already failed both of your `if`s there), and `not much` isn't part of your predefined greetings - so you end up in the response for 'unknown greeting'.

With these sorts of things it helps drawing the behaviour you want as a [state chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram), the visual representation usually makes it more obvious when you're missing a step.